# Eventbrite ticket Display

Tags: php, wordpress, eventbrite

Hello I need to fetch the ticket iframe from Eventbrite to a wordpress page. I purchased the ticket plugin and is 
getting PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context for the following Function

for the following function for inlcude line

```
public function displayEventBriteTicketForm() {
    include( TribeEventsTemplates::getTemplateHierarchy( 'ticket-form', 'hooks', 'eventbrite', $this->pluginPath ) );
    include( TribeEventsTemplates::getTemplateHierarchy( 'ticket-form', 'modules', 'eventbrite', $this->pluginPath ) );
}
```

Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the Problem

replaced `$this->pluginPath` with `$pluginPath` resolved the error message